# Duda con xpath y selenium webdriver en java

Tags: java, eclipse, firefox, xpath, selenium-webdriver

No consigo con Java y webdriver que me haga click en un XPath.

La página web es la de Movistar: www.movistar.es/Privada/DesafioUnico

Aquí está la imagen y el comando que tengo puesto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola DJuez. Por favor, lee el [tour]. Respecto a tu pregunta, puedes cambiar la imagen del codigo por el texto? Para darle formato puedes seleccionarlo y pulsar `ctrl + k`. Para màs info, mira [ask]. Un saludo

Comment: no añadas imágenes, sino código. ¡Proporciona un [mcve]!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El elemento se encuentra dentro de un iframe, esto implica que debes cambiarte a ese iframe antes de intentar obtener el objeto:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe_principal");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[@class='ng-binding']")).click();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya lo he entendido y me funciona perfectamente.

Saludos ;)

Comment: Buenas, puedes valorar las respuestas como se indica [este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Ya te he votado que no sabía el funcionamiento, perdona y gracias otra vez ;)

Comment: No te preocupes, pero el voto tiene que ser sobre esta respuesta, para que otros usuarios que les pueda pasar lo mismo tengan esta respuesta como referencia de solucion.

Comment: Creo que ahora si que esta bien hecho ;) muchas gracias jeje

Comment: Perdona, una pregunta, y para salir del iframe es necesario ? ya que lleva a otra web y no me detecta el xpath que le estoy ordenando.
Gracias y saludos

Comment: Ya esta, defaultcontent, gracias.